# Can we update Spark Session in spark 3.4.0 using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to update/insert configuration after creating spark session.

I am trying to pass these configurations for reading data from Elasticsearch 8.8.1

I have tried with multiple ways:

1. Passing configurations in `option("name", "value")` after creating spark session.
2. Trying to pass configuration to sparksession by `spark.conf.set("name", "value")`.
3. Trying to create a new spark session with the following pattern:

`val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName(sparkConfig.appName).master(sparkConfig.master).getOrCreate()`

`spark.newSession().conf.set("name", "value")`

So, is there any other way to update/insert configuration to Spark Session in spark 3.4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```scala
spark.stop()
// set your new configs..
val newSparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
.appName(sparkConfig.appName)
.master(sparkConfig.master)
.getOrCreate()
```

Taken from the `getOrCreate` scaladoc:

> Gets an existing SparkSession or, if there is no existing one, creates a new one based on the options set in this builder

SparkSession is a singleton so if you want to update its config afterward then you will have to `stop()` it before.

> stop the underlying sparkContext

Also about `newsSession` the scaladoc says it keeps the `sparkContext`, and consequently its `sparkConf`:

> Start a new session with isolated SQL configurations, temporary tables, registered functions are isolated, but sharing the underlying SparkContext and cached data